# export const functionName props undefined when using redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-functional-component

I am trying to understand how to get the props to show up when exporting a functional component like this

```
export const functionName = ({...props}) => {
  console.log(props); // undefined
  return <p>Hello</p>
}

functionaName.propTypes = { // propTypes here }
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ // state stuff here })
const mapDispatchToProps = { // props mapping here }
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(functionName); // works like it should
```

The normal method works as it should

```
functionaName.propTypes = { // propTypes here }
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ // state stuff here })
const mapDispatchToProps = { // props mapping here }
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(functionName);
```

I am trying to organize my imports and have a folder structure like so

```
components
  item // contains the component
    index.jsx
  index.js


  index.js
  export * from './item';
```

Then doing an import would be like this

```
import { functionName } from '../components';
```

My actual code does have a return value, I just truncated it for this post. Any ideas on how to accomplish what I am looking to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this code to work:

```
import { functionName } from '../components';
```

You need your `components/index.js` too look like this:

```
import { someFunction } from './item';
export someFunction;

// Or one liner:
export { someFunction } from './item';
```

Here are some examples from one of my projects:

```
export { default as AutoSuggest } from './AutoSuggest/AutoSuggest.react';
export { ErrorLog } from './ErrorLog/ErrorLog.react';
export { default as IconsBar } from './IconsBar/IconsBar.react';
export { JobDetails, JobEntry, JobGraph } from './Job';
export { default as LogsViewer } from './LogsViewer/LogsViewer.react';
export { default as Menu } from './Menu/Menu.react';
export { default as MultiSelect } from './MultiSelect/MultiSelect.react';
export { default as Notifications } from './Notifications/Notifications.react';
export { default as Panel } from './Panel/Panel.react';
export { ColorProperty } from './Theme';
```